# how to find similar tuples after grouping using pig latin?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a data which has the following structure -

1 John US
2 Mary CN
3 Smith US
4 John US
5 Mary CN

I need to find duplicate names within each country. Result should be something like this 
{US : (1, John, US),(4,John, US)}
{CN : (2, Mary, CN),(5, Mary, CN)}. Could someone help me with a Pig script for my problem?

I'm able to load the data and group it by Country Name.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have the input in the following format:

```
1 John US
2 Mary CN
3 Smith US
4 John US
5 Mary CN
```

In that case you can come up with the followings:

```
A = load 'data.txt' using PigStorage(' ') 
      as (id:int, name:chararray, country:chararray);
B = foreach (group A by (country, name)) generate group.country, A, 
      COUNT(A) as count;
C = foreach (FILTER B by count > (long)1) generate country, A;

dump C;
(CN,{(2,Mary,CN),(5,Mary,CN)})
(US,{(1,John,US),(4,John,US)})
```